# Context does not reach the pagein python-django from views.py

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app and I am trying to send some context views.py to a particular page:

```
status = True
context = {'status': status }
    return render(request, "sample/Newsample.html",{"form":ProfileForm() } ,context)
```

But the context does not reach the Newsample.html . Any mistake in syntax of code? the ProfileForm() is some method in my forms.py which I believe has nothing to do with context.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context that is passed to template by render is 3rd parameter , so you need to update your code as

```
status = True
context = {'status': status ,
           "form":ProfileForm()
          }
    return render(request, "sample/Newsample.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
status = True
context = {'status': status }
return render(request, "sample/Newsample.html",{"form":ProfileForm() } ,context)
```

should be

```
status = True
context = {'status': status , 'form': ProfileForm()}
return render(request, "sample/Newsample.html", context)
```